# How to fetch "Reply-To" attribute from email by using mailman (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, mailman

I am polling emails from my rails application by using Mailman gem. I followed the Railcasts [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1tYqIOt97Y)

In that Railscasts, Ryan Bates showed how to retrieve the Subject and the Content from the email that we received, and I could follow that just fine.

But now, I want to fetch the other attribute from the email, more specifically the **"Reply-To"** attribute. So how could I do this?

I have tried to do this like this: `message.Reply-to`, but I got

```
undefined method `Reply' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fc0fd641890> (NoMethodError)
```

when I tried to test it. Below is the screenshot of the full error message:

[image]

**Below is my mailman_server file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"

#Mailman.config.logger = Logger.new("log/mailman.log")

Mailman.config.pop3 = {
  server: 'pop.gmail.com', port: 995, ssl: true,
  username: "xxxxx@gmail.com",
  password: "xxxxx"
}

Mailman::Application.run do
  default do
    puts "Received: #{message.Reply-To}"
  end
end
```

**Below is my mailman_test.eml file:**

```
Date: Fri, 25 February 2016
From: myappsender@gmail.com
Subject: Mailman Test
To: myappsupport@gmail.com
Reply-To: myappreply@gmail.com
```

Comment: define: 'not working'

Comment: @Ecnalyr i got the `undefined method `Reply' for <Mail::Message:0x007fc0fd641890> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Did you try accessing it by key? Obviously `Reply-To` isn't a valid Ruby symbol. Alternatively, the API likely has a way to access headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mailman` gem internally uses `Mail::Message` while processing the incoming mail.

So you have access to all the methods of `Mail::Message` at your disposal. One of those methods is `reply_to`. So you could try `message.reply_to`.

Refer to [Mail::Message Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Message) for more info.